# How to create entire <li> clickable and then show box on top during mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, hover, mouseover

I have a list and it has some details inside it. What I like to do is for each of the list to be clickable and then upon mouse over, a box on top of the list will show which contains further info.

This is the list:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then on mouse over, I like to superimpose another box/div on top of it (which when they click, would go to another page):

```
<div>
   <h3>Title</h3>
   <p>More description ... </p>
</div>
```

An example of this effect is on this site:

http://www.hungrygowhere.com/ (DBS Special Indulgences section)

I don't know what script is being used. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this!

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4zvMG/8/)

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.description').stop().fadeTo(300, 0.7);
},function(){
     $(this).children('.description').stop().fadeTo(300,0);
});

$(".description").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a:last").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT**

added `.stop()` to prevent animation bubbling on repeated mouseovers.

Comment: Catandmouse, glad that helped

Comment: this prevents option-clicking from working, btw. you can't hold down option while clicking a link to open it in a new tab.

Comment: @JoeVanDyk May you please explain, I'm a bit lost in your comment... what 'option' are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I guess the term is 'middle click'. Whatever you use to tell your browser to open a new tab by clicking when a link.

Answer (score 2):

With some modifications to your html, then can be achieved using jQuery's `slideToggle()` to show and hide different elements of your `<li>`

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="one">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p> asd asd asd as dasd More description ... </p>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.one, .two').slideToggle(200);
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/phRnZ/1/

Comment: Thanks. But do you have an idea how do I make the entire <li></li> a clickable area?

Comment: @catandmouse But if you superimpose a div over the initial `li` ... why you bother yourself making `li` clickable?

Comment: @roXon: The list area is sort of big so I want the entire thing to be clickable. The description could be long or short. If short, then there's a big space at the bottom of that superimposed div.